Create a table in Sheet2 by iterating through rows in Sheet1
I want to use VBA to create a table for import to our ERP system.
Desired state: I press a button on Sheet2, the VBA code iterates through each row of a power query table on Sheet1, then paste each row into Sheet2 and have a row number generated for each iteration.  The resulting VBA table should have all the values / rows from the table in Sheet1, as well as row number for each loop iteration and columns with static values for data import formatting purposes (ex: the "min_qty" and "next row" in target table below).
example:
source power query table in Sheet1:



Item
Attribute




001
Red


002
Blue


003
Purple


...
...


099
Cyan



Target table in Sheet2 (before code is run)



Item
Attribute
row_nbr
min_qty
next row












Target table in Sheet2 (after code is run)



Item
Attribute
row_nbr
min_qty
next row




001
Red
1
1.01
yes


002
Blue
2
1.01
yes


003
Purple
3
1.01
yes


...
...
...
...
...


099
Cyan
99
1.01
yes



The length of the item dimension table in Shee1 is variable, so I would need to have the iterator stop at the end of the table object or when the value in that table is a blank string (i.e. ""), whatever is best practice.
One last thing, to avoid replicating data imported to the ERP system, I would want to have the VBA code clear out all of the cell contents of the VBA table's destination range if any exists.  I am thinking something like what the CurrentRegion function does to select all tabular data.  For example, if last import was 700 rows, but this one is 600 rows, there will be 100 rows from the last import if VBA doesn't clear out old contents.
I really appreciate any guidance, as I have no experience with VBA coding myself.

This is not a good site if you don't have any VBA knowledge at all - questions with only a specification and no code tend to get closed.  If you need to learn some VBA in order to get started, there are plenty of resources out there which can show you the basics.  It doesn't even seem like you need VBA for this though - a copy/paste and some fixed values would be quick, with maybe a formula for the row number....

It's something that can be quite easily done with Power Query. VBA doesn't strike me as the best took for the job.

Update Excel Table

It is assumed that each table is the first table (.ListObjects(1)) in its sheet.

Sub UpdateTable()
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim slo As ListObject: Set slo = sws.ListObjects(1) ' or e.g. "Table1"
    If slo.ListRows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No data in source table """ & slo.Name & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slo.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim dlo As ListObject: Set dlo = dws.ListObjects(1) ' or e.g. "Table2"
    
    ' Copy values.
    With dlo
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        End If
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then .DataBodyRange.Delete
        With .HeaderRowRange.Offset(1).Resize(srCount)
            .Resize(, 2).Value = slo.DataBodyRange.Value ' source table data
            .Columns(3) = dws.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & srCount & ")") ' row numbers
            .Columns(4) = 1.01 ' constant
            .Columns(5) = "yes" ' constant
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Table """ & dlo.Name & """ updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

